# LiveConnectClient resume interrupted download

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm using DownloadAsync method to download a file from OneDrive. Sometimes the download is interrupted and downloaded file incomplete. According to OneDrive REST reference, an app can resume the download by using HTTP Range header.

How do I add a header to LiveConnectClient call? I cannot figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I switched to BackgroundDownloadAsync method. With this method, downloading continues when app is deactivated or even closed.